# Calling consecutive DLL's from {tmp} in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I want to use a DLL (lets say 'A.dll'), that I created in Delphi, within my Inno Setup script that uses a bunch of other DLLs ('B.dll', 'C.dll', ...). All these dll-files are included in the Files-section as follows:

```
[Files]
Source:"libs\*.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
```

In the code section I declare methods of the used DLL as described in the Online help and add the **loadwithalteredsearchpath** flag:

```
procedure MyMethod; external 'MyMethod@files:A.dll,B.dll,C.dll stdcall loadwithalteredsearchpath';
```

When the installer starts, all needed files are copied into the temporary directory the constant {#tmp} is pointing to. However, *MyMethod* starts its execution just fine (checked it with some Showmessages), but the whole thing breaks, when the method tries to use the other DLLs.

Next to the temporary folder from {#tmp} two other temporary directories are created during the setup (all with the 'IS-xxxxx.tmp' pattern), which contain 'setup.tmp' (which is not occurent in {#tmp}). When I now manually copy all the DLL's (besides A.dll) into both these other directories at the beginning of the setup, then everything works fine. But when I let it run only as defined in my script, then A.dll doesn't seem to find the other libraries.

Does anybody know, why this is happening and how I can fix this? This seems to be a problem with the PATH, but I thought that Inno Setup adds the tmp-dir into the PATH, so that the setup can find the DLL's (which it does, but strangely only for A.dll).

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

**EDIT**: The actual error I get, when I use one of the 'foreign' DLL's (B.dll, C.dll, ...) by calling one of their methods inside of A.dll during the Inno Setup:

```
Access violation at address 00408CC7 in module 'setup.tmp'. Read of adress 00000000.
```

**EDIT 2**: I think I realized why my problem is happening: With **ExtractFilePath** (first link) in my own A.dll I discovered, that the setup.exe is not executed within {tmp} but one of the other two temporary dirs that are creating at the beginning of the setup. It also appears, that not {tmp} but the current working dir (thus the dir, where inno is executed) is added to the library search path (second link). This would explain, why the other libraries (B.dll, C.dll, ...) can only be accessed when manually copying to this other temp dir. I suppose that A.dll is extracted and called from {tmp} without a problem, because it is referred as the "main-library" in the *external* command. I thought that with **loadwithalteredsearchpath** the other libraries could remain in the same directory, but that doesn't seem to work.

But how can I fix this now in an nifty way? I think I could copy the DLLs manually to the setup-path (by using **ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))**, after they have been extracted to {tmp} to solve the problem. But this seems to be a dirty workaround as using DLLs in Inno Setup is supposed to work differently.

1. [How to get path where is temporary Inno setup file is located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152707/how-to-get-path-where-is-temporary-inno-setup-file-is-located)
2. [External function calls with multiple dependent DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836902/external-function-calls-with-multiple-dependent-dlls?rq=1)

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some other dependency of those three DLLs that they're relying on, or some other error?  Because typically load errors result in not being able to call anything in the DLL, not in it partially executing.

Comment: Well, I am not completely sure. But I tested the setup beforehand in a simple Delphi program, where all libraries (A.dll, B.dll, C.ll, ...) are in the directory of the program-exe and everything just works fine. It doesn't appear to be a load error to me, as the other libraries (B.dll, C.dll, ...) are also integrated just fine, but it just breaks when I want to use one of them (call one of their methods). -> Added the actual error I get.

Comment: "Read of address 0" sounds like a null pointer access.  Make sure that when you compile the libraries you use a "normal" link, not a delay-load link.  And that of course you don't have any null pointers in the DLL code you're actually running.

Comment: I created A.dll without any specific settings when exporting the methods, so I guess I'm using a "normal" link.

I have figured out, that there is in fact a null-pointer in my DLL, but I don't think it is caused and fixable by my own program. The point is, that I am using a component (TChromium from DCEF3) whose methods are mainly using the other libraries (B.dll, C.dll ...), while I don't have any influence on both. When I call the constructor of this compoment in Inno Setup no error appears, but the corresponding variable has no pointer, so any next access will fail (see error in main post).

Comment: But I don't think it's an error of my A.dll, because
 
1. I testet it outside Inno Setup in a seperate delphi-program and it worked just fine and

2. the emergence of the error in Inno Setup only depends on whether I manually copy the DLL-files in the said tmp-folders and not on any program changes.

So my guess is, that whenever I use one of the other DLLs by calling the components methods (like the constructor), they cannot be found although being within the same directory.

(Sry, for two comments, but I was not able to express myself within the character-boundaries :-( )

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if you only load the DLLs without registering them in the system registry. However your first EDIT shows an error triggered by attempts to access some stack of the registry, so I assume you are. In that case, I simply use a batch file (which fires commands in the CMD console) to register my DLLs as I would one by one:

```
 @echo off
 echo Registering DevExpress DLLs
 %~dp0gacutil.exe /i %~dp0DevExpress.BonusSkins.v12.1.dll
 %~dp0gacutil.exe /i %~dp0DevExpress.Charts.v12.1.Core.dll
```

So, I place this in the RUN section of the iss script:

```
[Run]
Filename:C:\myFolder\RegisterDevExpress.bat"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: DLL lirabries are not being registered as long as they are not e.g. .NET libraries (which is where you use gacutil), or they are not exporting `DllRegisterServer` functions (which is where you use Regsvr32). And once again, why would one use a batch script if you have the whole `[Run]` section for yourself, as well as powerful Pascal Script code engine behind your back. No, it must be just ancient batch script embedded in the setup... `</surrender>` :)

Comment: @TLama that is right on these being Dot.Net libraries (I assumed). Can you expand on registering each DLL file using the Pascal script: what's the exact format? (I often get error)

Comment: In case of .NET assemblies you don't need gacutil (and you should not be using it as it's part of the VS if I remember that right). You can simply specify the [`gacinstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=gacinstall) flag in your `[Files]` entries and the rest will Inno Setup do for you.

Comment: @TLama thanks. Like I said, when I use that approach I get error:   "Parameter "StrongAssemblyName" must be specified if the flag "gacinstall" is used." How would I proceed. (Should I post this as new question thread here?)